# UnityEvent retrieve the configured parameter

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using UnityEvent in Unity5. I use a script to have some logic that determines which of the confured methods are called. Therefore I do not use the Invoke method on the UnityEvent, but

```
            MonoBehaviour listener = m_Triggers.GetPersistentTarget(i) as MonoBehaviour;
            String name = m_Triggers.GetPersistentMethodName(i);                
            MethodInfo methodInfo = listener.GetType().GetMethod(name);
            object[] parametersArray = new object[] { };
            methodInfo.Invoke(listener, parametersArray);
```

Now I send en empty parameters array, but I would like to pupulate this array with the configured parameters in the editor. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think you'd need to store the array in a class and call a method from your event which lies in that class. I don't think there's any short-hand to do it. Can you explain more what you want to do?

Comment: I'd like to have the user specify 5 methods with optional parameters through UnityEvent in the editor. In code, instead of invoking the UnityEvent, which calls all methods, I'd like to apply my own logic and choose which methods are called. All works, except for retrieving the set parameters.